# Why is ethers estimateGas very inaccurate when estimating the cost for contract deployment?

Tags: ethers.js

I have deployed [this Simple ERC20 contract on Goerli](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x80523fc6285b174873e7739db3488a03c799bd680a5960684e137d37c8c8ceef) to understand the gas amount required to deploy it.

I can see that it cost `1,252,517` wei to deploy, because on Etherscan it tells me:

`Gas Limit & Usage by Txn: 1,252,517 | 1,252,517 (100%)`

However, when I use ethers to estimate the gas cost ahead of time, it tell me `Got the gas estimate 53000`. Here is the code that produces this result.

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.AlchemyProvider("goerli", alchemyApiKey);
const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, bytecode, wallet);
const estimatedGas = await provider.estimateGas(contractFactory.getDeployTransaction(args[0],args[1],args[2],args[3],args[4]).data);
console.log("Got the gas estimate " + estimatedGas);
```

This is extremely inaccurate. Which leads me to my question...

**Why is ethers estimateGas very inaccurate when estimating the cost for contract deployment?**

Comment: You may want to post an issue or look around https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues?q=estimategas for example https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/3846